# Regex match everything after a certain character (b) except a another character (closing curly brace)

Tags: r, regex

**Problem:**

I have a string, `{aabb.1234}` - those curly brackets are included. I'm trying to make a regex to match everything after the second `b` *except* that last closed curly bracket `}`. In other words, I need to match a period and everything after it.

**What I've tried:**

So far I have the first part, which identifies everything after the second `b`: `\.[^.]+$`, but I'm at a loss on how to make the `}` an exception. Thoughts?

Edit: I'm planning to use this regex inside `R`'s `gsub` function. If that makes a difference in your suggestions.

Comment: May be just `\.[^}]+` would work for you

Comment: `[^.]+` does not mean _"everything after the second `b`"_. It means any character except dot (`.`), one or more times. If you want to stop matching on the first `}` (not including it) then put `}` inside the negating character class (i.e. `[^}]+`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match the last curly bracket with a non capturing group and what you want with a normal group. You can then access your desired string with group #1 of each match.

```
(\.[^.]+)(?:})$
```

[here is a working example](https://regex101.com/r/7wxJYO/1)

*Edit per the question update:*

It works with R, as well, note group #1 of the match. [See here](https://regexr.com/5ue6t) at regexr.

[image]

Comment: Great website -- I'd only ever used regexr.com but this one is much better and clearer. But maybe I should've said -- I'm using this regex inside of `R`, which I hear is a little funky with regex. I've double-escaped the `\` in your suggestion with `\\`, but my result still doesn't "keep" the `}`. I'll keep fiddling with it, but any insight you might have would be a huge help!

Comment: It works with R as well, not group #1 of the match. https://regexr.com/5ue6t

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```regex
(?<=[^b]b).*?(?=\}|$)
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
(?<=[^b]b)  assert that what precedes is the first b (itself preceded by a non b)
.*?         then match all content until reaching
(?=\}|$)    a } or the end of the input
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `sub` like

```r
sub('.*\\.([^}]+).*', '\\1', '{aabb.1234}')
```

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/Du8Grl) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zc3gLT/1). Note that `gsub` replaces all occurrences, while `sub` replaces the first one, and `sub` is enough since here, the whole string is matched, and replaced with a backreference to Group 1.

*Details*:

- `.*` -  zero or more chars, as many as possible
- `\.` - a dot (it is double escaped in the R string literal, as `\` is used to form string escape sequences, such as `"\n"` (a line feed char, etc.)
- `([^}]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than a `}` char (`[^...]` is a negated bracket expression in a TRE regex)
- `.*` -  zero or more chars, as many as possible (the rest of the string)

The `\1` in the replacement  refers to the value of Group 1.